# Metric for dispersion that corrects for sample size

Tags: spatial, dispersion

I'm looking for a metric to measure dispersion of a set of points in 2D (or higher dimension) space. [This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13272/2d-analog-of-standard-deviation/13274) gives some examples, such as the sample mean of all points to be the center point and taking the average distance from the center point.

However, this dispersion metric produces a smaller value when the sample size is small. For example, a sample with 1 point has dispersion 0; a cluster with only 2 points will have sample dispersion that underestimates the true value. This makes it difficult to compare the dispersion of sets of points with different sizes.

Is there any way to correct for this sample size bias? Or a different dispersion metric that's unbiased with respect to sample size?

Comment: One of the answers in your linked question suggests dividing by $n-2$ rather than by $n$ (in one dimension it is common to divide by $n-1$ instead of $n$).  This might address the concern you raise

Comment: Interesting, I cannot find any justification for the $n-2$ though